# Is there a word for countable seconds, hours, days , months ,years?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I am a coder .
I want to write a `function` like

```
def process(dataframe, preiods=7, freq='hour') :
    ....
```

It can process dataframe by every `preiods` of `freq` .

But I think `preiods` is not a good word at here, preiods(plural preiod) looks stange too .

Do I use `period` correctly? If not, any good idea ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for a variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer the underlying language question. What to name your variables may be governed by the naming conventions of the shop or the programming language.

The preposition **by** is not idiomatic in that locution. We say that something should happen **every seven hours** or **every two minutes** not "by every".

Your program is giving the caller the ability to specify the *type of interval* (hours, minutes, days, etc) and the length of the interval.  We can call "hours" and "minutes" an *interval* or an *interval type*, and "seven" a "length" or a  "frequency".

`We want this to happen every {frequency} {interval type}`.

> Phone me every ten minutes.
>
> Push this button every sixty seconds.
>
> Send me an invoice every three months.